# Receiving NameError in Python when fetching data in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, nameerror

What can be wrong with this script that gives me a NameError, please?

```
import os
import tarfile 
from six.moves import urllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz" 

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz.path)
housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
housing_tgz.close()

fetch_housing_data()
```

This is the error:

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
 NameError: name 'housing_path' is not defined
```

Comment: Because `housing_path` is already outside of the function `fetch_housing_data`, you can no longer access. Replace `tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")` with `tgz_path = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "housing.tgz")`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a whitespace problem: the 5 lines starting with `tgz_path = ...` need to be indented so they are part of the `fetch_housing_data()` function.

```
import os
import tarfile 
from six.moves import urllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz" 

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path) # <-- not 'tgz.path'
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()

fetch_housing_data()
```

Otherwise, the interpreter will execute `tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")` outside the method, so the `housing_path` variable will be out of scope, and you'll get an error.

ALSO, `tarfile.open(tgz.path)` looks like a typo: should be `tarfile.open(tgz_path)`